# Python read issue in excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi I am new to the open source tech - I am using Anaconda3-5.1.0-Windows-x86_64 & Microsoft Excel 2016.The Excel reading operation using pandas throws error as File not found error for the below code.

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import ExcelWriter 
from pandas import ExcelFile 
path= "D:\sample.xlsx" 
print(path) 
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = 'Sheet1') 
print('Column headings:') 
print(df.columns)
```

The error message is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\sample.xlsx'-

I was trying to read 'D:\sample.xlsx' but the function tries to open file as 'D:\sample.xlsx'.

Can anyone please advise on this issue or shall let me know any more details required.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: apologies I tried pressing Ctrl+K but the code was not highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
path= "D:\sample.xlsx"
```

to

```
path= r"D:\sample.xlsx" or path= "D:\\sample.xlsx"
```

Comment: Have tried with  path= "D:\\sample.xlsx" - Same Error as File not Found & with path= r"D:\sample.xlsx"  error is                                with open(filename, "rb") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\\\sample.xlsx'

Comment: Additonal logs as 
  <pre> <Code> File "d:\Profiles\kgowdama\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 116, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:

Comment: Are you sure you have the file in `D:\sample.xlsx` ?

Comment: What error did you get when u used `path= r"D:\sample.xlsx"`

Comment: This is the Error when I used path= r"D:\sample.xlsx" Error Details
       File "d:\Profiles\kgowdama\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 116, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\sample.xlsx'